# Pandas: re-assign values for groups to same value in one column if they have at least one common in another

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"zip":['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A','C', 'C', 'C','C', 'C', 'C'],
                   "zip_splitted":['A_1', 'A_1', 'A_1','A_1', 'A_1', 'A_1', 
                                   'A_2', 'A_2', 'A_2','A_2', 'A_2', 'A_2', 
                                   'C_1', 'C_1', 'C_1', 'C_1', 'C_1', 'C_1'], 
                   "cluster":['111', '111', '111', '112', '112', '112', 
                              '113', '113', '113', '114', '114', '114', 
                              '115', '115', '115', '116', '116', '116'],                  
                   "cluster2":['991', '991', '994', '991', '882', '991', 
                               '993', '991', '994', '992', '991', '991',
                              '889', '889', '992', '998', '997', '999']
                  })
```

| zip | zip_splitted | cluster | cluster2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A_1 | 111 | 991 |
| A | A_1 | 111 | 991 |
| A | A_1 | 111 | 994 |
| A | A_1 | 112 | 991 |
| A | A_1 | 112 | 882 |
| A | A_1 | 112 | 991 |
| A | A_2 | 113 | 993 |
| A | A_2 | 113 | 991 |
| A | A_2 | 113 | 994 |
| A | A_2 | 114 | 992 |
| A | A_2 | 114 | 991 |
| A | A_2 | 114 | 991 |
| C | C_1 | 115 | 889 |
| C | C_1 | 115 | 889 |
| C | C_1 | 115 | 992 |
| C | C_1 | 116 | 998 |
| C | C_1 | 116 | 997 |
| C | C_1 | 116 | 999 |

Main target is to re-assign values in 'cluster', so that if groups of values in 'cluster' have at least 1 same value in 'cluster2' value - they should be combined with same cluster id.

For current case output should be following (cluster 111,112,113,114,115,116 - have at least one common vlaue in cluster2, re-assign them to 111, 116 - keeps the same):

| zip | zip_splitted | cluster | cluster2 | cluster_new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A_1 | 111 | 991 | 111 |
| A | A_1 | 111 | 991 | 111 |
| A | A_1 | 111 | 994 | 111 |
| A | A_1 | 112 | 991 | 111 |
| A | A_1 | 112 | 882 | 111 |
| A | A_1 | 112 | 991 | 111 |
| A | A_2 | 113 | 993 | 111 |
| A | A_2 | 113 | 991 | 111 |
| A | A_2 | 113 | 994 | 111 |
| A | A_2 | 114 | 992 | 111 |
| A | A_2 | 114 | 991 | 111 |
| A | A_2 | 114 | 991 | 111 |
| C | C_1 | 115 | 889 | 111 |
| C | C_1 | 115 | 889 | 111 |
| C | C_1 | 115 | 992 | 111 |
| C | C_1 | 116 | 998 | 116 |
| C | C_1 | 116 | 997 | 116 |
| C | C_1 | 116 | 999 | 116 |

Currently stuck with groupbys, trying to create a list for mapping, but not sure it's a correct way.
Appreciate any help.

Comment: Does it have to apply sequentially? What if cluster group `114` does not contain any value from prior groups but contains value from cluster group `116`, should  `116` popup inplace of `114` ?

Comment: this sounds like a graph/network problem.

Comment: Yep, if 114 has only common with 116, they both should be 114.

Comment: Graph - do you mean to use connected components? But how to implement it for this case?

Comment: I see, @rhug123 already implemented it - looks cool and elegant, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import networkx as nx

L = df.groupby('cluster')['cluster2'].agg(list)
G=nx.Graph()
for l in L:
    nx.add_path(G, l)
df = (df.assign(cluster_new = df.groupby(df['cluster2'].map(
    {v2:k for k,v in enumerate(list(nx.connected_components(G))) for v2 in v}
    ))['cluster'].transform('first')))
```

Output:

```
   zip zip_splitted cluster cluster2 cluster_new
0    A          A_1     111      991         111
1    A          A_1     111      991         111
2    A          A_1     111      994         111
3    A          A_1     112      991         111
4    A          A_1     112      882         111
5    A          A_1     112      991         111
6    A          A_2     113      993         111
7    A          A_2     113      991         111
8    A          A_2     113      994         111
9    A          A_2     114      992         111
10   A          A_2     114      991         111
11   A          A_2     114      991         111
12   C          C_1     115      889         111
13   C          C_1     115      889         111
14   C          C_1     115      992         111
15   C          C_1     116      998         116
16   C          C_1     116      997         116
17   C          C_1     116      999         116
```

Answer (score 0):

Created solution with pandas iterrows() which is working also, but graph approach is looking better and probably faster.

```
new_cluster_ids = {}

# Iterate over each row in the dataframe
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cluster = row['cluster']
    cluster2 = row['cluster2']

    # Check if the cluster already has a new ID assigned
    if cluster in new_cluster_ids:
        new_cluster_id = new_cluster_ids[cluster]
    else:
        new_cluster_id = cluster
    
    # Find other rows with the same cluster2 value
    same_cluster2_rows = df[df['cluster2'] == cluster2]
    
    # Update the new cluster ID for all rows with the same cluster2 value
    for _, same_cluster2_row in same_cluster2_rows.iterrows():
        new_cluster_ids[same_cluster2_row['cluster']] = new_cluster_id
    
df['cluster_new'] = df['cluster'].map(new_cluster_ids)

print(df)
```